# JQuery Autocomplete Initialize as a Separate Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have multiple pages on which I need to initialise a JQuery Autocomplete with the same ajax source, is there a way I can take the initialisation and make it into a seperate function, which I can then call in each of my pages. This is what I want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    do_autocomplete();
});
```

And in a seperate file, ie functions.js

```
function do_autocomplete() {
    $("#personname").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
            return response(data);
        }
        });
    }
    }).bind("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).autocomplete('close');
    $('#personid').val(ui.item.id);
    });
}
```

Currently this does nothing (although it works when the function code is used instead of the function call). I can't seem to find anything about this sort of thing anywhere so am hoping someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work fine, assuming you have `<script src="functions.js"></script>`. Make sure the function is defined globally, not inside another function.

Comment: The js file is definitely included (as I am using other functions from it without problem) and it is defined globally. I'll keep playing around, at least I know I'm on the right track, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should include this file at the end of code or after the page is loaded.

Comment: The functions.js file is included in the header of the web page. Calling the function inside $(document).ready(); means it doesn't happen until the page is loaded. Is this correct?

Comment: $(document).ready() gets triggered when the DOM is complete, not necessarily when the entire page is loaded. So you need to make sure your javascript file with the function is loaded entirely before the DOM is complete and the code triggers.

Comment: Got it! Fantastic, thankyou! (I moved the include to the top of the header instead of the bottom.)

Comment: you are using the divs personname and personid in the function, defining functionality before they are created, does not work. You Must define the function when divs are created.